# WriteTrace and WriteEvent

Tags: logging

According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512746.aspx
I have to use this code
   WriteTrace(System.UInt32, Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsCategory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.TraceSeverity, System.String, System.Object[]);
            WriteEvent(System.UInt16,Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsCategory,Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.EventSeverity,System.String,System.Object[]);

However after adding that code and the using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration; it generates compile time errors., as if those methods dont exist.

Please help

Comment: I still have a question, the write event, writes to the event log, but what about the writetrace, where can I see that info?

Comment: Are you running your solution in the sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware when they are referring to the trace logs they are referring to the log files found in the LOGS folder of the 12 hive or in the case of SharePoint 2010 the 14 Hive or 'SharePoint Root'. Have a look in the latest log file for your trace message you wrote using the WriteTrace method and it should be there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do it using this link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservicebase.writetrace.aspx

However I still have a question, the write event, writes to the event log, but what about the writetrace, where can I see that info?

Thx